# How to make Angular "see" methods in a child service injected with useClass?

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, service, web-component

I had a bunch of Angular components that had mostly the same code, so I created a component to contain that repeated code, mostly general methods for dealing with the data from the backend and handling it in the forms. I had to create an abstract service to do that, since each form used it's own service, though they were quite similar.

The "parent" component calls the methods for handling the data in the service (the child component extends the parent, though it's not abstract), and the way the service is created in the child is that the annotation @Component has a "useClass" to the child service, so it's created as the parent service, e.g. provide: MotherService, useClass: ChildService (the "MotherService" is an abstract class that declares all the methods used in the common component, "ChildService" extends it and implements it's methods corretly).

The thing is, on one of the components, that I'm making extending from the parent one, I have to call some extra methods from the service, since it uses multiple tables from the DB and the parent service only handles a main one.
I called the super in said method and then added the rest of the code that I needed, using methods exclusive to the child service. The code worked as expected, but the terminal gives me an error for each method called that's only from the child service:

```
ERROR in src/app/.../child/child.component.ts(63,8): error TS2339: Property 'methodThatMotherDoesntHave' does not exist on type 'MotherService'.
```

The code runs normally, but it seems Angular expects the parent service to have all the methods called, since the function that calls it is called from the code in the parent component himself, I guess?!? Even VS Code shows the methods in red and suggests that they need to be created ("Property 'methodThatMotherDoesntHave' does not exist on type 'MotherService'."). How can I "declare" that this methods exist in the child service, that is actually being injected in place of the parent service?

I haven't tried to rework the code since the error is quite unusual and the code itself runs exactly as expected. I've read a bit about other types of injection like "UseExisting" but it didn't seemed like it was going to help immediately.

Main component:

```
export class MotherComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: Data[];

  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    public service: MotherService,
    ...
  ) { }

  public getData() {
    this.service
      .getData()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        ...
      });
  }
...
}
```

Child component:

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: MotherService, useClass: ChildService }
  ]
})
export class ChildComponent extends MotherComponent {
  public data2: Data2[];

   public getData() {
    super.getData();

    let data2: Data2[];
    this.service
      .getData2()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(
        data2 => {
          this.data2 = data2;
      );
  }
...
}
```

Abstract Service:

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class MotherService {
  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClientService) { }

  getData() {
    return new Observable<any>();
  }
}
```

Child Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ChildService extends MotherService {
  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClientService) { }

  getData() {
    return this.httpClient.get('blablabla/whatever/getData').pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        if (!response) {
          return [];
        }
        return response.Data.map(data => new Data().initializeWithJSON(data);
      })
    );
  }

   getData2() {
    return this.httpClient.get('blablabla/whatever/getData2').pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        if (!response) {
          return [];
        }
        return response.Data2.map(data2 => new Data2().initializeWithJSON(data2);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I wanna get rid of the errors in the terminal and in VS Code by making Angular recognize that the methods that are being called actually belong to the child service, not the parent one (maybe by making some weird declaration of them, perhaps? But I have no idea how to do so).

Comment: You are providing the wrong class. If your component needs `ChildService` then you should provide `ChildService` and not `MotherService`. Everything else are just TypeScript error messages because you're ignoring the types.

Comment: When I try and provide ChildService by itself, I get an injection error (StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MotherComponent -> MotherService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MotherComponent -> MotherService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MotherService!). I believe the child component needs to provide the MotherService since it extends the mother component (I had a lot of trouble to figure that out in the beginning).

Comment: Remove `@Injectable()` from `MotherService`.

Comment: Removing @Injectable() from it makes it unable to inject the service (Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ChildService: (?)).